# GTK TreeView Vertical Scroll Bar in Julia

Tags: treeview, gtk, julia

I have a TreeView setup using GTK in Julia.

Currently when I load my items into it, its height is unbounded and it expands depending on how many items are added.

How can I add a scroll bar to my GTK TreeView so it does not expand in height but simply allows for scrolling?

I have looked around and cannot find this anywhere for the Julia programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You add the TreeView to a ScrolledWindow (using the standard container `add()`) method. Refer to the `set_scroll_policy()` method to enable or disable specific scrollbars.

Be sure to also read [the regular C GTK+ docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/); they are the main source of information for GTK+.